# Pharo Smalltalk print Friday days

Tags: calendar, smalltalk, pharo

I want to print from the first year to 1582 (where the calendar is changing) the days that are 13 and on friday (for instance 13 September 2019 is on Friday).

I try this code but it doesn't work. Can you help me please?

```
   #code 
   (Date year:1 month:1 day:1) to:(Date year:1 month:10 day:5)
   do:[:i| 'Friday' weekday and weekdayIndex >>> 5|Transcript show:i ;cr]
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple bruteforce attempt would be to collect all the 13ths of each year from for example 1 to 1582 and then select those that are fridays:

```
|thirteenths friday13ths|
thirteenths := (0 to: (12*1582)) collect: [ :each | (Date year:1 month:1 day:13) addMonths: each ].
friday13ths := thirteenths select: [ :each | (each weekday) = 'Friday' ].
```

The Collection `friday13ths` has all the Friday 13ths for the timespan.